# JavaScript Namspacing - "Java like" packages with objects?

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm currently developing an app which is going to be huge (with a few hundred Objects/Classes, etc.) and I'm wondering if there are any drawbacks if I'm going to organize the Classes in Objects which will "act" like `packages` like this:

```
var App = {};

App.models = {};
App.models.todo = {};
App.models.todo.TodoModel = function () {};
App.models.todo.TodoCommentModel = function () {};
```

and so on... it would help me a lot to structure my code (in my opinion) but I'm not shure how this would affect the load time / performance of my app? Is this common / good practice or is it *evil* (in terms of performance ...).

Comment: Is this going to be a single page app?  If not, do you need all of the hundreds of objects to be loaded on each page?  To answer your question I've seen many apps structured this way so I believe it's pretty common.

Comment: @CalebJoshuaMingle sorry, I forgot to mention this: yes, it's a **single page app** :)

Comment: Your solution is the way that I have done it in the past but I know there has been a lot of people going the way of solutions like RequireJS but I do not have direct experience with it.  It keeps you from polluting the global namespace and having large namespace chains (which will happen, trust me!) and requiring only what you need for a certain piece of code.  Something to keep in mind maybe :)

Comment: I'm doing the same with my app and I even split the code into several files, there are no drawbacks.

Comment: The performance impact from property access lookup is usually minimal in "normal" web applications.